# How to retrieve data from Firebase without EventListener?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

I am using Firebase on my Android app and I know how to get data from the database with an EventListener. Well so far.

My problem is this: I have a ReciclerView which shows information from data but only when I modify the database. If I close the app and open again, it doesn't show anything. Then, I modify something and appears all my elements in the container.

Is there any way to load this data no waiting for an event, but getting manually?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE 1 (This is my code which works perfectly):

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            listaDeLyrics.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot lyricFromFB : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    LyricCard lc = lyricFromFB.getValue(LyricCard.class);
                    listaDeLyrics.add(lc);
                }
            }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

I want to get data with no using EventListener.

SOLUTION: I fix it saving data from the database before creating the RecyclerView. It seems display nothing because the list was empty (but I don't understand why it didn't response to changes on the list)

NOTE: addValueEvent works also the first time even modifying nothing. It gets information when it is declared, and then, also when an event happens. singleValueEvent works exactly the same with difference it only do once, just the first event listened.

I hope this can also help someone.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: I think is not needed add any code. I have no errors. It is just a question. But okey i will share a part of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening probably because you're using `addValueEventListener()` which will add a listener to a reference and listen for changes in that reference(path).

What I recomend is to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` which will query that reference only once and then dettach from it. Therefore, if you do this everytime your activity opens you'll have the updated values everytime.

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       //parse data to recycler view adapter and call notifyDatasetChange()
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

However you must use eventlisteners to read your firebase database, there's no other way.

Comment: Thank you! I have realized that the problem is that RecyclerView is not notified the first time. Anyway, SingleValue doesn't retrieve data directly, it needs an event as AddValue, but it only takes once.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, please use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener`. The `ValueEventListener` is triggered every time something changes in your database.

Change this and try to print the result in your `onDataChange()` method.

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot lyricFromFB : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                LyricCard lc = lyricFromFB.getValue(LyricCard.class);
                Log.d("TAG", lc.getLyricCardName());
            }
        }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

I have used, this following line of code:

```
Log.d("TAG", lc.getLyricCardName());
```

Assuming you have a getter named `getLyricCardName()`.

From the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) pelase see:

> addListenerForSingleValueEvent(ValueEventListener listener) - Add a listener for a single change in the data at this location.
>
> addValueEventListener(ValueEventListener listener) - Add a listener for changes in the data at this location.

One more thing, there is no way in which you can retrieve data without using a listener at all. Everything in Firebase is about listeners.

Comment: Thank you! I have realized that the problem is that RecyclerView is not notified the first time. I tried with Log, as you said, and I noticed that it gets all information but RecyclerView doesn't retrieve. Anyway, SingleValue doesn't retrieve data directly, it needs an event as AddValue, but it only takes once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use firebaseUI to fetch data from your firebase database into your recyclerview directly. EventListeners are not required, you can get the data just by calling the adapter with:

adapter.startListening();

You can get the full documentation here.
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: I am sure it works in this way. I was reusing a normal recycler view which shown information from SQLite database.

Answer (score -1):

You might be listening for child events, you should [listen for value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events), it returns entire list of data in a single snapshot which you can loop on, as compared to the child events, which are triggered only when a child is added / updated.

**UPDATE**

If you want to get data without any EventListener, then simply use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, which just get the data once and do not listen for any further events.